# iAD Banner not showing, everything seems right

Tags: ios, iad, ads

I have a Dutch app called "Rollerbank" in the App Store. In the Netherlands iAds are allowed.
So in my application I have "self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;" in all my view controllers. When testing it shows test ads.

But when I released the app, the iAd panel didn't work (temporarilty unavailable), even after waiting for a month.
Then I decided to to update my app, with importing iAd in the Appdelegate m and h file. I also created a AdView property in the delegate (that isn't used).
When the update was released the iAd panel finally worked.
After 3 weeks there are still NO ads in my app. I asked a lot of friends to try, but no ads :(
This is what iAd shows me:

[image: iAd]

and this:

[image: iAd 2]

I really don't know what the problem is. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you actually have an issue with iAd. As you can see it says that Ads are live and you are getting some impressions.

The issue here seems to be that your iAd fill rate (the rate that ads are presented to places that have iAd - like the US) is incredibly low. I would suggest contacting Apple Customer Support about the fact that your ads are not working.

Since you are seeing test ads in your simulator, have the live ads notice in iAd workbench, and have had impressions means that there isn't an issue with the code.